# Is it possible to use Plain Cement Concrete post for fencing?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, stresses, structures, strength

I am in need of around 700-800 posts to fence my farm in a semi-arid area in TN state, India. In my place granite posts mined from quarries are normally used. It costs around Rs 300-400 per post(6-7ft). I want to use plain cement post instead of the costly granite post. As it has no rebar, it costs around Rs 170-200, and as it has no iron, it can have long life without corrosion. The posts are used to tie 6-7 nos of GI barbed wire to safeguard the property.

I want to know , whether its feasible to use PCC post for fencing. If its not, how to incorporate iron rebars without the risk of corrosion in the long run. Please suggest.

Comment: Better possibly on Home improvement. But check before posting.

Comment: It is possible, but concrete without ductile reinforcement is too brittle to resist lateral force. You shall consult with a structural engineer, to figure out the minimum amount of steel needed to serve your purpose.

Comment: Rebar life will be good in an "arid" location ; concrete bending strength will be poor with no rebar.

Comment: there has been some interesting work in combining concrete with other materials including plastic and fiber.  concrete should be expected to be very weak compared to those granite posts.  You might also be able to use a different geometry, but bigger = more cost.  you could coat the iron rebar in something if you are concerned about corrosion.

Answer (score 0):

It’s interesting that you know the price. Is there a supplier - if so, contact customers for their experience.

It’s my opinion that an un-reinforced post will break during lifting due to the bending moment tension within the concrete.

I wouldn’t expect corrosion of the reinforcement to be a problem. The steel should be at the center and covered by concrete. Not exposed to sea water mist.

He is a link to a design manual from cooperative extension outreach. [Concrete Fence Posts](https://oaktrust.library.tamu.edu/bitstream/handle/1969.1/166193/1368/Leaf1368.pdf?sequence=4&isAllowed=y)

Here is a photo from a supplier website showing deterioration:
[image: “Buy Our Brand”][Australian Concrete Posts](https://concreteposts.com.au/benefits/)